# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 while trying to run an exe file

Tags: java, javac

GP is a `.exe` file that I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/releases). When I'm trying to run it, I receive the following error:

```
C:\GPP> gp -list
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: pro/javacard/gp/GPTool : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

C:\GPP>
```

How can I handle it? Should I remove JRE and install a newer or older version?

My Current version:

```
C:\GPP> java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

C:\GPP> javac -version
javac 1.7.0_21

C:\GPP>
```

Is it possible to force Java use an specific major.minor version to run a program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install a Java 8 runtime as the application you downloaded was compiled with Java 8 as target platform.

Comment: May you please tell me how did you recognize the java version that this program is compiled with?

Comment: 52.0 corresponds to Java 8.

Comment: Where can I see other versions major.minor versions?

Comment: here is a list of versions: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0544.html